# Basic bond strength concept

Tags: bond

I saw C-H  bond is stronger than C-C bond... Is this because of the following reasons?
1) C-H bond is shorter than C-C bond.
2) C-H bond is more ionic than C-C bond.
I

Answer (score 0):

The bond strength depends on the atomic radius of both chemical elements which take part in their bond and their difference(the chemical elements) in electronegativity.

Just for the record C-H is not ionic, it is not even polar :P

Both C and H attract the bonding pair of electrons approximately the same.

Comment: Noooo I mean atleast more ionic due to C-C as there is electronegativity difference....u must be laughing on me so hard if u think that I think C-H bond is ionic

Comment: C and H have the same electronegativity.Their difference in electronegativity is so small , which can be neglected.

Comment: Yes but atleast more than C-C right?

Comment: Electronegativity of C is 2.5 and that of H is 2.1

Comment: The main difference between the bond energies is the atomic radius of carbon being bigger than the atomic radius of hydrogen. But yes it is more than C-C since in C-C it is zero.

Comment: 0.4 is a very small difference

Comment: Ok but what about overlapping. P-p overlapping is efficient than s-p

Comment: I don't what overlapping is. I know there are some bonds which are referred as σ and p but I cant tell you.Are you talking about molecular orbital theory?

Comment: Yes .... Not exactly but yes

Comment: well the shape of 1s subshell is spherical so the s-p bond would be stronger due to the fact the orbital 1s covers more area.

Comment: So more area in common between the 1s and the 2p orbital.

Answer (score 0):

Its true that overlap of 2p - 2p >2s-2p > 2s - 2s due to p's directional bond. But  1s-1s >1s-2p >2p-2p , because as size inncreases extent of ovelap decreases which means here 2 opposite factors act in which size factor wins.

But the thing is whn carbon makes bond with H its orbital overlapping with it is not pure p rather sp3, sp2 or sp. Infact C always make bond with these orbitals only, so it is not right to comapre pure orbitals overlapping.

H being shorter than C, and H-C having electronegative difference unlike C-C have higher bond energy as they r able to release more energy due to these factors.Actually ectronegativity plays a important role in explaining the bond energies mostly.